# RemoveFromSuperView() with animation - AnimationWillEnd does not trigger

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a UIView and try to remove it from its superview using an animation (fading to alpha 0.0). Works fine but the view is never removed from the superview although I added a delegate to AnimationWillEnd. Here's the code. The console output is not written and the view is not removed. What's wrong?

```
    UIButton oBtn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
    oBtn.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 20);
    oBtn.SetTitle("Hide", UIControlState.Normal);
    oBtn.Center = new PointF(80, 120);
    oBtn.TouchUpInside += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        UIView.BeginAnimations(null);

            UIView.AnimationWillEnd += delegate {
           Console.WriteLine("Removed.");
           oView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            };

    UIView.SetAnimationDuration(2);
    UIView.SetAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true);
    oView.Alpha = 0.0f;
    UIView.CommitAnimations();
   };
   oView.AddSubview(oBtn);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried a lot of things with your code but it seems that the UIView.AnimationWillEnd handler never gets called. There is a way however, to perform the task you want:

```
oBtn.TouchUpInside += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        UIView.Animate(2, 
            delegate {
                oView.Alpha = 0.0f;
            },
            delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("Removed.");
                oView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            });
   };
```

The second anonymous method gets called when the animation completes. You can check Animate's other overloads for more options.

Comment: I am not sure yet, I would like to try some other things as well before filing a bug for it.

Comment: ah sweet, i had no idea you could just provide delegates as NSAction

Comment: Yes you can. NSAction is a delegate after all...!

Answer (score 0):

The button needs to be defined outside of the scope of the method, otherwise it will get collected sooner than expected. Try defining the button at the class level, and then setting it to null in your AnimationWillEnd delegate.

Comment: That doesn't solve it. Furthermore, the button is added to the view I'm trying to remove, so there is still a valid reference and neither the button, nor the view will be GC'ed.