# Paint an image, wait 1 second then dismiss it

Tags: uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to paint a green box where the user touched the screen, wait 1 second, then dismiss the box. Any ideas why this code isn't working? The box never paints. If I use a thread, the animation wipes out the box.

```
public static void DrawClick(RectangleF rect, UIView theView)
    {
        var center = Center(rect);
        center.X = center.X + 30f;
        center.Y = center.Y + 30f;
        var greenRect = new RectangleF(center, new SizeF(60f, 60f));
        var clickView = new UIImageView(greenRect);
        clickView.Image = appDelegate.store.GetArt("greenbox.png");
        theView.AddSubview(clickView);
        //Wait 1 second
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        clickView.RemoveFromSuperview();
    }
```

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 2):

You block the main UI thread for 1 second, so there is no way for it to render.

One way to do it is with a `System.Timers.Timer` with a 1 second duration, making sure to call `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to update the UI when it fires.

Example [here](http://wiki.ios.xamarin.com/HowTo/Threading) of `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.  Here is one for [System.Timers.Timer](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-timers-in-c/).

A cooler option would be to use animations with the Alpha value, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708577/removefromsuperview-with-animation-animationwillend-does-not-trigger).